# Scrollbar disappear in post window

Tags: posts

[image]

Scrollbar has suddenly been removed without notice. How can I get it back? I am using Chrome

Answer (score 0):

can you specify the version you are using? Chrome version, WordPress version or if you are using Classic editor?